# Android: How to ensure the button is only enabled when there is has wifi conn or internet(mobile)?

Tags: android

The scenario

1.When there is wifi or internert(mobile) connection
the button is enabled

2.When there no wifi or internert(mobile) connection
the button is disabled

3.This checking is perform all the time and not just checking when the app is initialized and start

Comment: What is the question? What are you having problems with?

Comment: I need to write the code for the connection checking. The button in my app will disabled if no connection and only enabled if gt the connection. It is to prevent the force closed since my app take the data source from internet

Comment: Both methods described here will do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518636/check-network-connectivity-android/30518851#30518851

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your on create write this....

```
if(haveNetworkConnection()==true)
{
  yourbutton.setEnabled(true); 
}
else
{
  yourbutton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

And in your code add this for network checking.

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
    if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
        if (ni.isConnected())
            haveConnectedWifi = true;
    if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
        if (ni.isConnected())
            haveConnectedMobile = true;
}
return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
```

}

in your android manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for network connectivity with `IntentFilter(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)`

And check connection with

```
boolean isConnected(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

If there is Internet available or not you can display it in UI.